# If I can ping my DB server, is my SQL Server connection guaranteed to work?

Tags: sql-server, connection, tcp

If I can ping my DB server, is my SQL Server connection guaranteed to work?
I am using a default connection string in my code.
My program runs fine locally but overseas sites are having issues and I am wondering if SQL might be using a TCP or UDP port that is still blocked.

Here is the connection string "Data Source=xxxx.xxxx.com; Initial Catalog = xxxxx; User ID=xxxxx;password=xxxxx"

Comment: Here is the connection string "Data Source=xxxx.xxxx.com; Initial Catalog = xxxxx; User ID=xxxxx;password=xxxxx"

Comment: Is this a new setup or an existing setup that has been working before?

Comment: It works from the site where the server is at, but not from remote sites where IT blocks ports in between. I read I need TCP port 1433 open by default, I'm guessing it's not now.

Comment: You can try telnetting to the port to see if it is open.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I understand your question you are asking whether ICMP "ping" packet which returns guarantees you can open a connection on a particular TCP port? The answer is NO. It is also not the other way around - "ping" packets might be blocked by a firewall.

Answer (score 3):

`telnet xxxx.xxxx.com 1433` might be a better indicator.

Comment: ...assuming that is your SQL port. A much better method though.

Answer (score 0):

No. The SQL Server Service must at least be running on the server for any mssql connections to work. The server itself can be up - running and pingable without the SQL Server Serice running.

Answer (score 0):

You might also need to check whether the TCP/IP protocol is enabled using SQL Server Configuration Manager. Even when MSSQLSvc is running, it might not respond to remote requests.